# How to go from Bangkok to Bang Saen by motor transport in the least pricey way?

Tags: bangkok

I understand Bang Saen as the nearest beach to Bangkok; I further understand it was likely reopened yesterday (after it was closed due to the Coronavirus pandemic).

My prior research about this wasn't very fruitful and several Thai people I spoke with were not sure themselves but I assume the answer would be bus or a van; and yet:

Should this bus be taken from *JatuJak*, *AnuSawariChay*, or from *Ekammai*?
The only vans I recall encountering in **2020** at AnuSawariChay are to Min Buri.

How to go from Bangkok to Bang Saen by motor transport in the least pricey way (in 2020)?

Comment: Cheapest options for any type of travel tend to be walking, bicycling & hitch-hiking, since they are mostly free. Other than that check out https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Bangkok/Hat-Bang-Saen

Comment: According to https://www.nationthailand.com/news/30388735 the beach is still closed. It'll reopen next Monday.